# CSS advanced hover effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

I'm fairly new to coding, and this is my second repo on Github! I’m looking to do a specific hover effect. I have a custom designed typeface in PNG format that I would like to appear as overlay on hover. If the typeface was in TTF format, this would be so easy... but it was hand drawn and edited in Illustrator. I have 12 clickboxes on the same page that I want to apply this effect to, is it possible to use PNG on hover? So far, I have only ever set up my CSS to basic 2px line or color overlay hover effect, like so:

```
div.clickBox-Ministries:hover{
border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
```

OR

```
div.clickBox-Ministries:hover{
background-color: #1380BB
opacity: 0.3;
cursor: crosshair;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I think you're looking for is a selector like so:
`.common-parent:hover .png-overlay{}`

you're also going to need to use `position:absolute`, `top:0`, and `z-index:1`, to get the positioning right.

**don't forget to `position:relative` the parent element**

Here's a demo to explain this a bit better:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stackoverflow.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <style>
            .clickBox-Ministries, 
            .png-overlay {
                

                width:500px;
                height:200px;
            }
            .clickBox-Ministries{
                background-color: aqua;
            
            }
            .png-overlay{
                background-color: bisque;
            } 
            .png-overlay{
                /* good practice to hide elements with display none. prevents screen reader from still reading it*/
                display:none;

                /* puts */
                position:absolute;
                top:0;
                z-index:1;

                opacity:0;
            }
            .common-parent{
                /* prevents any child elements with position:absolute; from being positioned relative to body element instead of it's the parent object */
                position:relative;
            }
            .common-parent:hover .png-overlay{
                /* reset display from previously being hidden */
                display:inline;
                
                opacity:1;
                /* makes the transition smooth --- really handy to know this property */
                transition: opacity 0.1s ease-in-out;
            }


        </style>

        <div class="common-parent">
            <div class="clickBox-Ministries">

            </div>
            <img class="png-overlay" />
        </div>



    </body>

    </html>
```